# Open Graph objects and "can_post"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been playing around with Open Graph Objects.

I know you can only publish to objects that have been liked and are not of the type "article", but I've been noticing something with some of the objects I'm testing. When I go to:

```
graph.facebook.com/http://my_object_url.com/
```

I have  line that says:

```
"can_post": true
```

Is this possible that the value goes to 'false' and if yes, what would be the cause of that?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is undocumented `field` and there is couple of BUGS ([#133489650086613](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/133489650086613) and [#231837450231710](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231837450231710)) about documentation updates exists

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been noticing some bugs too, that's why I was worried about this field.